# Wordpress getting single post ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a theme template and when i try to get post ID it returns the ID of the template not the ID of the actual single post.

the template ID is: 215 
the post ID is: 1911
the following code will only output 215

```
function metavalue() {
                    global $post;
                    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_url', true);
                    return $meta;

                }
                add_shortcode('url_short', 'metavalue');
```

get_the_ID(); the_id(); $post->ID; will also output 215. i need a way to get the actual single post ID so i can get the custom field value from 'product_url'.

Comment: can you show more of your code please ? where do you try to output the post ID ?

Comment: Thats all the code there is, i'm just trying to get the data from the custom field 'product_url' and output it on the single post. I just cant get the data because the above code returns the ID of the template and not the ID of the single post that has the custom field associated with it.

Comment: can you output the value of the `$post` array in your question ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "template ID" ? In WP terminology templates generally mean simply theme's PHP templates, they don't have post objects associated with them.

Comment: @Rarst I'm using newspaper theme from themeforest, it has a visual page builder for creating single pages. on the back end the template is assigned an ID(215 in this case), $post->ID is returning the template ID(215) instead of the single post using the template (1911).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted support with the theme authors on this topic as well but for the time being i've found a way to work around it.

```
function metavalue() {
global $wp;
$url = home_url( $wp->request );
$correct_post_id = url_to_postid( $url ); 
$meta = get_post_meta($correct_post_id, 'product_url', true);
return $meta;
}
                add_shortcode('url_short', 'metavalue');
```